# How do I remove water from my base?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I decided to build an underwater glass dome to try and recreate Atlantis. It worked fine, but only one problem: It's filled with water! How do I remove all of it?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Related - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174994/how-can-i-clear-the-water-out-of-this-area/175015#175015

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to handle this:

- Use a bucket to rid the world of the water source blocks one by one
- Use a level editing tool to remove the water in a procedural fashion (faster if you know what you're doing, for large areas), turning each water block into air
- Use a mod
- Use sponges (creative mode helps with this)
- When building a lot, you may find you have plenty of spare blocks of dirt or sand. Placing blocks in the same space as water will rid the space of the source block, so that when you remove your dirt/sand, air is let behind. This is my favorite solution, because I'm a low tech luddite.

There you go! Several ways.

Comment: Note, the sponges will only work in snapshots 14w25a or later.

Answer (score 2):

Fill with sand and then remove the sand again. =)

Answer (score 1):

In creative, you can use a program like MCEdit to remove the water.

A good strategy in survival is to go into a forest of a jungle with shears, cut off all the tree leaves, then fill the water with them. They break fast and you never run out.