# Best way to find all water in certain area in survival Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What's the best way to find all (or most of) the water in an area in a Minecraft world (to be able to remove it)? Especially water in caves is a problem.

Comment: Id say the easiest would be to use the the fill or replace block command (idk a lot about mc commands so thats why this is a comment). Unless you cant use commands, then really the only way would be to do it manually.

Comment: it's more about locating it and getting to it inside caves and stuff

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174994/how-can-i-clear-the-water-out-of-this-area

Comment: This question talks about getting rid of water when you know where it is... I just don't know where it is

Comment: All of your question talks about removing water, not finding it. You edited a single sentence in at the end that goes in a complete different direction than everything before it and the title is still incorrect. Please ask two questions if you have two questions and write what you mean if you have one question. About your problem: If you could find water easily, you could probably find everything easily and that's not the point of the game. But I have one thing that could help you, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a big part of Minecraft is finding resources, the game won't make it too easy for you. You will have to go through the caves and search for it.
But to find water in particular, you can make your task a bit easier by turning subtitles on. Flowing water produces sound and if you have subtitles on, you not only see it clearly no matter how far away or quiet it is, but you also get an indicator if it's to the left or to the right of you.
As soon as you see the subtitle, you can dig into the direction it shows you.

The downside of this is that you can't find standing water that way, but those are mostly just single blocks, apart from very rare water pockets with multiple water sources. Both are only a small part of the water in the world, so they shouldn't make a big difference for your farm. If they do, you would just have to search more.

Answer (score 1):

**This was about an earlier version of the question. Apparently the asker didn't mean this, but worded it poorly.**

= The manual way =

You can let sand fall into the water to split it into columns (7x7 should be good) and then drain it with sponges.

It should probably be the easiest to go into the water, place one sponge on the sand wall, break it, place the next one lower down etc. while you go down with the water. Then you use an ender pearl, elytra or pillaring to get back up and repeat it with the next column.
Alternatively you could also drain the top, then break the top of the sand walls, then drain more, etc., but getting the sponges back would be more difficult that way.

At the end you can break the sand either with a good shovel (instamining) or by breaking the lowest block and quickly placing a torch in its place.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYQfF3k931w) is a video about it.

= The automatic way =

Since you're apparently a person that likes farms, this might be more your thing: You can build a flying machine and item dispensing system to automatically fill everything with sand. This works best in a rectangular area.

Since it would be quite difficult to explain the whole flying machine in text and pictures, I'll just link a video:

Comment: how about water inside caves?

Comment: Water inside caves is never there in a big amount, you can just use whatever tactic you like. Place blocks, make sand fall, pick up with buckets, turn into stone using lava, ...